# iOS in-app purchase; works on sandbox, not on production

Tags: ios, node.js, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app with auto-renewing subscriptions where I'm using the [in-app-purchase Node.js module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/in-app-purchase).  Subscription purchase works in the sandbox (deployed via xCode or downloaded via TestFlight), but in production the Node.js module doesn't appear to be calling [my success or failure handlers](https://gist.github.com/BrianGeppert/5b382750aba139ba926f).

To simplify/troubleshoot the code, I changed it so it uses `Date.now` instead of the purchase date.

Comment: Can you try making a normal HTTP request to apple's servers and see what you get back?

Comment: The error ended up being in the frontend code, not the backend code.  Thanks for the help!  Am waiting to delete this.

Comment: Can you describe what your problem ended up being? I'm having this same issue. Attempting a purchase with a sandbox user works, however the process isn't initiated for real-world users.

Answer (score 3):

Look lower on the page for in-app-purchase where they talk about subscriptions. Have you checked your password for iTunes?

```
iap.config({
  applePassword: "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef"
});
```